# Geodjango - Error when try to run server

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango

I am trying to setup up `Geodjango` in my newly created project. I followed all steps given in django documentation. But when I try to run server following error occurs:

[image: python.exe - Entery point not found]

After clicking OK the same window appears again and then after clicking OK following appears on console:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

My **Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '*********',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and my **Models.py**:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Why do you have dot after your `Port`? Shouldn't it be like **`'Port' : '5432'`** !!

Comment: I corrected it but problem is same...

Comment: gdal was installed correctly?